# node.js i18n: "ReferenceError: __ is not defined"

Tags: node.js, cron, internationalization, i18n-node

Throughout my app I use `i18n` without problem. However, for email send through a cron job, I get the error:

> ReferenceError: __ is not defined

In `app.js` I configure i18n:

```
const i18n = require("i18n");
i18n.configure({
    locales: ["en"],
    register: global,
    directory: path.join(__dirname, "locales"),
    defaultLocale: "en",
    objectNotation: true,
    updateFiles: false,
});
app.use(i18n.init);
```

Throughout my app I use it as `__('authentication.flashes.not-logged-in')`, like I said without problems. In a mail controller, that is called upon by a cron job, I use it in the same way: `__('mailers.buttons.upgrade-now')`. However there, and only there, it produces the mentioned error.

Just to try, I've changed this in the mail controller to `i18n.__('authentication.flashes.not-logged-in')`. But then I get another error:

```
(node:11058) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: logWarnFn is not a function
    at logWarn (/data/web/my_app/node_modules/i18n/i18n.js:1180:5)
```

Any idea how to make the emails work that are sent through a cron job?

Comment: How is your cron job set up, exactly? Does it make an HTTP request to your app, or does it try and use `node` to run the controller directly?

Comment: @DylanSp, I don't know much about cron and haven't set this up myself, so I hope I'm answering your question correctly. If I run `crontab -l` I have `30 14 * * * cd /data/web/portal/ && /usr/bin/timeout 120 /usr/bin/node cli.js sendemails 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -t portal-cron-live`. I think this means node tries to run the controller directly, does it not?

Comment: It depends what `cli.js sendemails` does. Does that script make an HTTP request, or call the controller directly?

Comment: Ah, that calls on the controller directly: `program.command("sendemails").action(async function () { mailController.executeCrons() ...`

Comment: There's your problem; the `i18n` global doesn't get defined that way. I'll type up an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In comments, the asker clarified that the cron job calls `mailController.executeCrons()` directly, instead of making an HTTP request to the app. Because of this, the `i18n` global object never gets defined, because the app setup code in `app.js` isn't run.

The best solution would be to use `i18n`'s [instance usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n#as-instance). You could separate the instantiation and configuration of an `I18N` object out into a separate function, then call it both in `app.js` to set it up as Express middleware, and in the `mailController.executeCrons()` function to use it when being called through the cronjob.

Code outline:

`i18n.js` (new file)

```
const i18n = require("i18n");

// factory function for centralizing config;
// either register i18n for global use in handling HTTP requests,
// or register it as `i18nObj` for local CLI use
const configureI18n = (isGlobal) => {
  let i18nObj = {};

  i18n.configure({
    locales: ["en"],
    register: isGlobal ? global : i18nObj,
    directory: path.join(__dirname, "locales"),
    defaultLocale: "en",
    objectNotation: true,
    updateFiles: false,
  });

  return [i18n, i18nObj];
};


module.exports = configureI18n;
```

`app.js`

```
const configureI18n = require('./path/to/i18n.js');

const [i18n, _] = configureI18n(true);
app.use(i18n.init);
```

`mailController.js`

```
const configureI18n = require('./path/to/i18n.js');

const [_, i18nObj] = configureI18n(false);

executeCrons() {
  i18nObj.__('authentication.flashes.not-logged-in');
}
```

Comment: I'm trying the solution now, but referencing app.js it produces the error: `const [i18n, _] = configureI18n(true);` `TypeError: configureI18n is not a function or its return value is not iterable`.

Comment: Sorry, messed up the export syntax. Edited `i18n.js` to use `exports = configureI18n;`, try that.

Comment: It works as expected, but it doesn't add the keys to the locale file automatically.